# Function to conditionally split values of a list

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, split

I try to split values exported with selenium into excel by considering also the articles and any prepositions.
For example my list is:

```
Neon Five Apple A incandescence The book
```

I want to use:

```
for l in lst:
    list_elem.send_keys(l)
```

Bul wil take values like this:

```
Neon,Five,Apple,A,incandescence,The,book
```

What I want to obtain when sending keys is:

```
Neon,Five,Apple,A incandescence,The book
```

Is there anything I could add here before sending keys?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1], 'col2': ['value4, value5, value6']})
```

Comment: can you please post sample dataframe?

Comment: @Anurag Dabas, done, it takes values from the first row of col2

Comment: Does the answer on this question help? Please take the time to upvote and/or mark it as the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ntlk can be of use here I think. It would depend on the actual data contained in your df. I generated some random English lorum ipsum.

You then use nltk to tokenize and tag the words. Then use the tags in the `if` statement in the function to add them to the next word. You can find a list of the tags [here](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html). You'll need to play a bit to get the exact results you want.

I also included a way to put manual exclusions in there, mostly for the punctuation marks.

```py
import nltk
from pprint import pprint


# download data sets
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')


dummy_text = '''The European languages are members of the same family.
Their separate existence is a myth.
For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary.
The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words.
Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators.
To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words.
If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages.
The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages.
It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.
To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is.
The European languages are members of the same family.
Their separate existence is a myth.
For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary.
The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words.
Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators.
'''


# use only lowercase words in this exception list
my_exceptions = ['a']
ignore_tags = '.,;:'


def create_list(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    # see https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    pprint(tagged)

    results = []
    current = ''
    for word, nltktag in tagged:
        if (
            nltktag == 'DT' or 
            nltktag == 'VB' or
            word.lower() in my_exceptions
        ):
            current = f'{current}{word} '
        elif nltktag not in ignore_tags:
            results.append(f'{current}{word}')
            current = ''
    return results


pprint(create_list(dummy_text))
```